# Number of dimensions practically possible when using copulas for multivariate probability distribution sampling

Tags: distributions, sampling, multivariate-analysis, copula

I have a high dimensional data set (depending on how I try to estimate it, anywhere between 6 - 100 variables) and I'm trying to sample from the underlying multivariate probability density. I can easily construct marginals for each variable by itself, and am trying to build copulas to allow me to sample from the multivariate distribution. I've been using the [copulas](https://pypi.org/project/copulas/) python package on 2D subsamples of this data and the sampled data looks pretty good in relation to the actual underlying data used to build the model.

However, there's a big difference between 2D and, say, 100D. I am curious about two things:

1. Practically speaking (either in terms of data required, computational cost, memory, algorithm limitations, etc.) how many variables could I include in building the multivariate distribution?
2. Assuming I can build distributions greater than dimension 3, how could I evaluate the quality of the underlying samples given that I can no longer visualize the sampled data vs the original data in the higher-dimensional space?

Comment: Ad 1) This depends of course on the distribution you would like to model. If all 100D are exchangeable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables) then it is as easy as 2D, if not ...
Ad2 ) That depends on what you are trying to achieve. You should have a clear idea of what you are trying to model and then you have to simply test this property.

Comment: Thanks. My dimensions are not exchangeable, unfortunately. At first I had hoped there might be a better, more universal answer to (2) than the one you give above. However, upon a bit more reflection, maybe testing whatever property I want to be preserved with the copula approach is exactly right. I have some ideas about how I might do that that I'll try.

Comment: Would vine copulas offer any advantages in modeling such high dimensional data compared to regular copulas?